# How to concat results of parfor loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, parallel-processing, parfor

I'm running parfor loop that returns matrix with different dimensions at each iteration, I need these matrices to be concatenated for the final result

for example

```
T = [1 2 3 0
  7 8 9 10]
```

I compute for each row the maximal block which should return

for the first row

```
 [1 2
1 3]
```

and for the second row

```
[7 8 9 
 7 9 10]
```

my code is

```
parfor i = 1:size(T,1)
   findMBL(Data,T(i,:));
end
```

where findMBL is the function that returns the blocks. 
my problem is how can i concat the results of the iterations in one matrix

The result should be

```
[1 2 0
1 3 0
7 8 9
7 9 10]
```

Note: zero in row 1 and 2 is padding

Comment: In general, you dont need to worry about anything while using parallel toolbox. If there is somethign to worry about generally Matlab will ut a warning.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the maximum size of the result, its easy to do.

```
% I am completely guessing this, substitute for realistic maximum possible size
res=zeros(2*size(T,1),size(T,2)); 


parfor i = 1:size(T,1)
   auxres=findMBL(Data,T(i,:));
   res([i*2-1,i*2],1:size(auxres,2))=auxres;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you help sir Ander, but it give me error: The PARFOR loop cannot run due to the way variable 'res' is used

Comment: ouch! I dont have matlab now so I cant try it! However, do what Ratbert suggests. Define res as `cell(size(T,1),1) and do `res{ii}=find...`

Answer (score -1):

You have to define a buffer cell, in which you will put your arrays at each iteration, and then use `cell2mat` to obtain the concatenated result.

Comment: Thanks Sir @Ratbert but could you show me how? I'm new to matlab and parallel computing